# OIDC user propogation

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a microservice architecture, both of them protected by spring security and JWT tokens. I am Using Okta as authentication service provider. When i pass the token as the header, i am always getting as unAuthorized. Individually i am able to hit both the API's.

Registered a webclient as specified below and using

```
@Bean
WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
                                 ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);

    oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth)
            .build();
}
```

//Calling the API from class

```
        List block = webClient.get().uri("URL String")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(List.class)
            .block();
```

//Error Message

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:176) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$createResponseException$13(DefaultWebClient.java:495) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:353) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:385) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1508) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:363) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:372) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:196) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:337) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:334) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:381) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:522) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:141) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297) ~[netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap(Mono.java:2490)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$null$1(DefaultWebClient.java:430)
Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$null$1(DefaultWebClient.java:430)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:429)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:199)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:199)
    |_  Mono.doOnNext ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:200)
    |_  Mono.doOnNext ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:201)
    |_  Mono.error ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleException(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:234)
    |_  Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:202)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:151)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:152)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.reactive.HttpTraceWebFilter.filter(HttpTraceWebFilter.java:78)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter.filter(AuthorizationWebFilter.java:46)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext ⇢ io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:900)
    |_  Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.filter(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:43)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter.filter(LogoutWebFilter.java:56)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter.filter(LogoutWebFilter.java:56)
    |_  Mono.map ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter.filter(LogoutWebFilter.java:57)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter.filter(LogoutWebFilter.java:58)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter.filter(LogoutWebFilter.java:59)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter.filter(ServerRequestCacheWebFilter.java:39)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:49)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:49)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:50)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:69)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:69)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.filter(LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter.java:70)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:91)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:91)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:92)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:91)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:91)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.filter(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:92)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.filter(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.java:104)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.filter(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.java:104)
    |_  MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext ⇢ io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:900)
    |_  Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.filter(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.java:105)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.filter(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter.java:106)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter.continueFilterChain(CsrfWebFilter.java:115)
    |_  Mono.then ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter.filter(CsrfWebFilter.java:94)
    |_  Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter.filter(CsrfWebFilter.java:94)
    |_  MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext ⇢ io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:900)
    |_  Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter.filter(CsrfWebFilter.java:95)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.flatMap ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy.filter(WebFilterChainProxy.java:58)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_  Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:84)
    |_  Mono.doOnError ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:84)
    |_  Mono.compose ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:76)
    |_  Mono.defer ⇢ org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)

    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: what is the full error?

Comment: updated with the error description